# CPU Utilization is different in multiple Availability Zones

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

CPU Utilization is different in different Availability Zones under single ELB of Auto Scaling.
Does it mean Amazon balance their load between AZ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Amazon will make sure the ELB is scalable and active, so they use their own best practices when doing so.

Also on another topic, you can put the servers behind it in separate ones as well:

> Using Elastic Load Balancing, you can distribute incoming traffic
>   across your Amazon EC2 instances in a single Availability Zone or
>   multiple Availability Zones. Elastic Load Balancing automatically
>   scales its request handling capacity in response to incoming
>   application traffic. http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/